# Simple Spring/AngularJS Rest Consumption Tutorial Won't Get/Display Data

Tags: json, angularjs, spring, rest, groovy

I'm following [this tutorial](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-consuming-rest-angularjs) exactly, but I can't seem to get the JSON content to load successfully.

Here are the files that I've created per the tutorial:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="hello.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="Hello">
            <p>The ID is {{greeting.id}}</p>
            <p>The content is {{greeting.content}}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

hello.js:

```
function Hello($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.greeting = data;
        });
}
```

app.groovy:

```
@Controller class JsApp { }
```

Here is the output from my running of the command `spring run app.groovy`:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Dev\rest-test>spring run app.groovy

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.5.RELEASE)

2015-09-02 22:52:00.032  INFO 1968 --- [       runner-0] o.s.boot.SpringApplicat
ion               : Starting application on asbs-dev with PID 1968 (C:\Users\me\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.2.5.RELEASE\spring-b
oot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar started by me in C:\Dev\rest-test)
2015-09-02 22:52:00.513  INFO 1968 --- [       runner-0] ationConfigEmbeddedWebA
pplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.Annotat
ionConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1336a56: startup date [Wed Sep 02 22:52:0
0 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-09-02 22:52:03.049  INFO 1968 --- [       runner-0] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListab
leBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver':
replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; auto
wireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBea
nName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$White
labelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodN
ame=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/spri
ngframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorView
Configuration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; laz
yInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=
false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConf
iguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver
; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resou
rce [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAu
toConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2015-09-02 22:52:05.578  INFO 1968 --- [       runner-0] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbedde
dServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2015-09-02 22:52:05.983  INFO 1968 --- [       runner-0] o.apache.catalina.core.
StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2015-09-02 22:52:05.987  INFO 1968 --- [       runner-0] org.apache.catalina.cor
e.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
2015-09-02 22:52:06.200  INFO 1968 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loa
der.WebappLoader  : Unknown loader org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.Extende
dGroovyClassLoader$DefaultScopeParentClassLoader@1adac6c class org.springframewo
rk.boot.cli.compiler.ExtendedGroovyClassLoader$DefaultScopeParentClassLoader
2015-09-02 22:52:06.279  INFO 1968 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[loc
alhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-09-02 22:52:06.279  INFO 1968 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.Context
Loader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5769
 ms
2015-09-02 22:52:08.356  INFO 1968 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegist
rationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2015-09-02 22:52:08.370  INFO 1968 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.Filter
RegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-09-02 22:52:08.371  INFO 1968 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.Filter
RegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2015-09-02 22:52:09.236  INFO 1968 --- [       runner-0] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMapp
ingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.cont
ext.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1336a56: startup date
 [Wed Sep 02 22:52:00 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-09-02 22:52:09.453  INFO 1968 --- [       runner-0] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMapp
ingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.Res
ponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframewo
rk.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServ
letRequest)
2015-09-02 22:52:09.455  INFO 1968 --- [       runner-0] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMapp
ingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.spr
ingframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web
.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-09-02 22:52:09.474  INFO 1968 --- [       runner-0] o.s.w.s.c.a.WebMvcConfi
gurerAdapter      : Adding welcome page: file:/C:/Dev/rest-test/public/index.htm
l
2015-09-02 22:52:09.525  INFO 1968 --- [       runner-0] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleU
rlHandlerMapping  : Root mapping to handler of type [class org.springframework.w
eb.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
2015-09-02 22:52:09.556  INFO 1968 --- [       runner-0] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleU
rlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class or
g.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-09-02 22:52:09.557  INFO 1968 --- [       runner-0] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleU
rlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.spring
framework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-09-02 22:52:09.723  INFO 1968 --- [       runner-0] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleU
rlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [clas
s org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-09-02 22:52:11.165  INFO 1968 --- [       runner-0] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBe
anExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2015-09-02 22:52:11.428  INFO 1968 --- [       runner-0] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbedde
dServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2015-09-02 22:52:11.429  INFO 1968 --- [       runner-0] o.s.boot.SpringApplicat
ion               : Started application in 12.111 seconds (JVM running for 17.50
4)
2015-09-02 22:52:17.615  INFO 1968 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[loc
alhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2015-09-02 22:52:17.616  INFO 1968 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.Dispatc
herServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started

2015-09-02 22:52:17.721  INFO 1968 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.Dispatc
herServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization complet
ed in 102 ms
```

*Additional details:*

- Windows 7
- Google Chrome

Any thoughts as to why the JSON won't display in the HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried your example in Firefox, I got the following in my browser console:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).`

I presume this is because your Groovy server is running in `localhost` or somewhere other than `rest-service.guides.spring.io`? By default, web browsers will block $http response that comes from different domain. You need to make sure that the remote server allows cross-origin request, which will in turn tell your browser that the response is a valid cross-origin request which will not be blocked.

The tutorial that you linked seems to be pointing to another tutorial on how to enable CORS in your groovy server, although the URL is dead. I looked around in github and seems like the tutorial is moved to https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service-cors